A problem with the CSS file appearing empty in the browser and not linking to the HTML files
I created a custom.css file and added it to the css folder. After that, I enter the site. It does not work. The file appears empty. I will attach the code and a picture from the browser.
.thumbnail .caption h3 {
    overflow: hidden
}

#BiBplayer {
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    height: 0
}

.controls-play-pause-big,.video-bibplayer-poster,.video-bibplayer-video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute
}

.icon-play,.icon-play:after,.icon-play:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    border-radius: 50%
}

.video-bibplayer-poster {
    z-index: 1;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover
}

.video-bibplayer-video {
    background: #000;
    z-index: 0
}

span.sc {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: visible
}

.video-bibplayer .controls-play-pause-big {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1
}

.video-bibplayer[status=playing] .controls-play-pause-big {
    opacity: 0
}

.video-bibplayer .controls .controls-time span,.video-bibplayer .controls .controls-volume[muted] .controls-volume-value,.video-bibplayer[no-controls] .controls,.video-bibplayer[no-controls] .title {
    display: none
}

.icon-play {
    z-index: 10;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    display: block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 44px;
    padding: 18px 20px 18px 28px
}

.icon-play:after,.icon-play:before {
    content: "";
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    display: block
}

.icon-play:before {
    z-index: 0;
    background: #2f323e;
    animation: pulse-border 1.5s ease-out infinite
}

.icon-play:after {
    z-index: 1;
    background: #دراما عربية;
    transition: all .2s
}

.icon-play:hover:after {
    background-color: darken(#fa183d,10%)
}

.icon-play img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto
}

.icon-play span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 32px solid #fff;
    border-top: 22px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 22px solid transparent
}

@keyframes pulse-border {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) translateZ(0) scale(1);
        opacity: 1
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) translateZ(0) scale(1.5);
        opacity: 0
    }
}

@media all and (max-height: 500px) {
    .controls-play-pause-big .icon-play {
        margin-top:0;
        top: 41%
    }
}

.video-bibplayer .controls {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px 1vw 0;
    z-index: 3;
    height: calc(4em + 4px);
    background: linear-gradient(transparent,rgba(0,0,0,.4))
}

.video-bibplayer .controls .controls-progress-bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 8px;
    right: 1vw;
    left: 8px;
    left: 1vw;
    height: 4px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.3)
}

.video-bibplayer .controls .controls-progress-bar-value {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 3px;
    width: 3px;
    background: #d50032
}

.video-bibplayer .controls .controls-full-screen,.video-bibplayer .controls .controls-mute,.video-bibplayer .controls .controls-play-pause {
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 2em
}

.video-bibplayer .controls .controls-play-pause {
    float: left;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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),none
}

.video-bibplayer .controls .controls-full-screen {
    float: right;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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),none
}

.video-bibplayer .controls .controls-mute {
    float: right;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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),none
}

.video-bibplayer .controls .controls-volume {
    float: right;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    width: 7em;
    height: 4px;
    margin-top: 1.8em;
    margin-top: calc(2em - 2px);
    margin-right: 1.5em
}

.video-bibplayer .controls .controls-volume-value {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 95%;
    background: #fff
}

.video-bibplayer .controls .controls-time {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    max-width: 55px;
    margin-left: 1.5em
}

.video-bibplayer .controls .controls-time i {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #fff
}

@media all and (max-height: 220px) {
    .video-bibplayer .controls {
        font-size:8px
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 300px) {
    .video-bibplayer .controls .controls-volume {
        display:none
    }
}

.pm-video-heading {
    padding: 20px 0
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width:480px) {
    .icon-play {
        width:14px;
        height: 22px
    }

    .icon-play:after,.icon-play:before {
        width: 49px;
        height: 49px
    }

    .icon-play span {
        border-left: 16px solid #fff;
        border-top: 11px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 11px solid transparent
    }

    .pm-video-heading h1 {
        font-size: 1.25rem;
        line-height: 2.25rem;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 4px 12px
    }

    #video-control {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 4px 0
    }

    .nav>li>a {
        padding: 5px 15px
    }

    .pm-video-description {
        font-size: .95rem;
        line-height: 1.5rem
    }
}

.hot,ul.episodes li a em {
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block
}

.pm-video-heading .pm-video-adjust {
    text-align: right;
    float: right
}

.SeasonsBox ul>li,.hot,.notesv,ul.episodes li a {
    text-align: center
}

.pm-video-heading h6 {
    color: #fc5;
    margin: 0
}

.pm-video-heading h6 a {
    color: #fff
}

.row.pm-video-control {
    display: block
}

.row.pm-video-control a {
    color: #999
}

.row.pm-video-control a:hover {
    color: #bbb
}

.row.pm-video-control form {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline
}

.row.pm-video-control .btn.btn-video {
    color: #999;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    background: 0 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-top: 10px
}

.row.pm-video-control .btn.btn-video:focus {
    outline: 0
}

.row.pm-video-control .btn.btn-video:hover {
    color: #bbb;
    background: 0 0
}

.row.pm-video-control .btn.btn-video.active {
    border-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none
}

.row.pm-video-control .btn.btn-video.active#bin-rating-like {
    color: #0dc209
}

.row.pm-video-control .btn.btn-video.active#bin-rating-dislike {
    color: #c20b09
}

.row.pm-video-control .btn i,.row.pm-video-control .btn:hover i {
    opacity: 1
}

.row.pm-video-control #bin-rating-dislike-confirmation,.row.pm-video-control #bin-rating-like-confirmation {
    position: absolute;
    top: -134px;
    border: 2px solid #fff!important;
    width: 240px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    color: #555;
    z-index: 1000
}

.row.pm-video-control #bin-rating-dislike-confirmation:after,.row.pm-video-control #bin-rating-dislike-confirmation:before,.row.pm-video-control #bin-rating-like-confirmation:after,.row.pm-video-control #bin-rating-like-confirmation:before {
    top: 100%;
    left: 8%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    margin-top: 2px
}

.row.pm-video-control #bin-rating-dislike-confirmation:after,.row.pm-video-control #bin-rating-like-confirmation:after {
    border-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: #fff;
    border-width: 8px;
    margin-right: 0
}

.row.pm-video-control #bin-rating-dislike-confirmation:before,.row.pm-video-control #bin-rating-like-confirmation:before {
    border-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: #e0dee0;
    border-width: 8px;
    margin-right: 0
}

.row.pm-video-control #bin-rating-dislike-confirmation .tooltip,.row.pm-video-control #bin-rating-like-confirmation .tooltip {
    z-index: 3000
}

.row.pm-video-control #bin-rating-dislike-confirmation a,.row.pm-video-control #bin-rating-like-confirmation a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 5px
}

.row.pm-video-control #bin-rating-dislike-confirmation {
    left: 80px;
    top: -88px
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 464px) {
    .row.pm-video-control #bin-rating-dislike-confirmation {
        left:50px
    }
}

.pm-video-main-methods li a i.mico {
    font-size: 20px
}

.notesv {
    background: #f6f9ed;
    border-left: 4px solid #ffc107;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-top: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 12px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: cairo
}

ul.episodes {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px auto
}

.hot,.ribon {
    position: absolute
}

ul.episodes li {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px
}

ul.episodes li a {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: #222;
    font-family: Arial #000;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    text-decoration: none
}

ul.episodes li a.active,ul.episodes li a:hover {
    background: #d82c2a;
    color: #fff
}

ul.episodes li a em {
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 2px
}

.ribon {
    left: -7px;
    top: -7px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px
}

.hot .after,.hot .before {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1
}

.hot {
    color: #fff;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 111px;
    background: #ff4136;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px #000;
    top: 19px;
    left: -30px;
    font-weight: 700
}

.hot .after {
    left: 9px;
    top: 100%
}

.hot .before {
    right: 5px;
    top: 20px
}

.pm-video-thumb {
    overflow: unset!important
}

.SeasonsBox>.SeasonsBoxUL {
    width: 210px;
    float: right
}

.SeasonsBox ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0
}

.SeasonsBoxUL>h4 {
    margin: 0 0 10px!important;
    background: #2f323e;
    border: 0!important;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px!important;
    padding: 0 20px!important;
    color: #fff
}

.SeasonsBox {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fbfbfb;
    margin: -12px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd
}

.SeasonsBox:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both
}

.SeasonsBox ul>li {
    height: 35px;
    background: #e4e4e4;
    color: #333;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer
}

.SeasonsBoxUL h2 {
    color: #fff!important;
    text-align: center!important
}

.SeasonsEpisodesMain {
    width: calc(100% - 225px);
    float: left;
    text-align: center
}

.SeasonsEpisodesMain a {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #2f323e;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff!important;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 7px 14px;
    border: 1px solid #999
}

.SeasonsEpisodesMain a em {
    display: block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: Arial #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    line-height: 20px
}

.SeasonsEpisodesMain a span {
    display: block;
    line-height: 20px;
    opacity: 1
}

.SeasonsBox ul>li.active {
    background: 0 0;
    color: #fff
}

.SeasonsEpisodesMain a.active {
    background: #010f13;
    color: #fff!important
}

@media screen and (max-width: 464px) {
    .SeasonsBox>.SeasonsBoxUL {
        width:auto;
        float: none
    }

    .SeasonsBoxUL>h2 {
        height: auto!important;
        font-size: 15px!important;
        line-height: 33px!important
    }

    .SeasonsBox ul {
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 20px
    }

    .SeasonsBox ul>li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 20px
    }

    .SeasonsEpisodesMain {
        width: 100%;
        float: none
    }
}

.showmore {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #2f323e;
    border-right: 5px solid #555;
    border-left: 5px solid #555
}

.pm-video-description .textv {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: #777;
    padding: 0 15px;
    position: relative;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block
}

.home-serie-item a {
    padding: 10px 5px;
    background: #2f323e;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1 1;
    font-zize: 15px
}

.home-serie-item {
    border-spacing: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 10px
}

.home-series-list {
    display: block
}

.home-serie-item a:hover {
    background: #096e7f
}


enter image description here

Are you sure you're loading the correct version of that file? Use the Network tab to check the request and the contents of the response

The path to the file is correct, and this image shows it from the Network menu
https://ibb.co/pdVzjvq

I’m unclear of the problem and/or relationship between the hundreds of lines of CSS, the empty file, and the three lines of CSS from the screenshot. I’m also unclear what PHP and/or JSON has to do with this.

Sir, the problem is that the file path is correct and the code is inside it, but when I review it in the browser, only three lines of code appear and it does not work and I do not know what the problem is.

Why do you say it is empty then? And your problem is really “I’m saving a CSS file to my web server, but when I access it in my browser my changes aren’t showing”, right? Have you flushed caches, or tried cache busting techniques such as adding a query string to the URL?

Your issue not with CSS code. Show us how you are running your dev server and code is being updated. Maybe restarting the setup would work. Maybe you haven't saved the file. We cannot give you any specific solution without knowing the right problem.
